# show border color when one div touches another one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs and one is fixed to top and I would like to show a border color for the fixed div when the second div touches it. I want just like what yahoo does.[image]

Here it is ...[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>

.containter{
 width:700px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
.header{
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background:yellow;
 }

 .content{
 min-height:500px
 width:100%;
 background:red;
 }
```

any way to do it using css or jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery to get this effect:

suppose this is your class which shows the shadow when window gets scrolled.

```
.shadow{
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #888888;
}
```

then add a jQuery when your window's scrolltop is greater than `0`.

```
$(function(){
    var $window = $(window),
        $header = $('.header'),
        $this   = $(this); // <-----here you can cache your selectors

    $window.on('scroll', function(){
       if($this.scrollTop() > 0){
           $header.addClass('shadow');
       }else{
           $header.removeClass('shadow');
       }
    }).scroll();
});
```

#### [Demo Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd64V/)

#### [Demo with cached vars](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd64V/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, you can detect when the page has been scrolled, and update content after it has scrolled past a certain point like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
        var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0);

        if(top > 100)
        {
            // Page has been scrolled past 100 pixels; add border here
        }
        else
        {
            // Page has not been scrolled past 100 pixels; remove border here
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Just apply a css rule to the fixed divider with jQuery using the `.css()` function and remove it the same way. This may look something like:

```
$('.header').css('border-bottom', '2px solid #F00'); // Add border
$('.header').css('border-bottom', 'none'); // Remove
```